# Is there a mathematical framework where both potential and actual infinity are used?

Tags: philosophy-of-mathematics

1) By actual infinity I mean that given **X**, it is inaccessible by **Y**, where **Y** is a placeholder for any possible non-finite set, such that no non-finite set is accessible to **X** (**X** is beyond the notion of collection of objects, where set is a particular case of collection).

2) By (1) any given non-finite set it is permanently under construction (it can't have an accurate cardinal number), which means that **Y** is defined in terms of potential infinity with respect to **X**.

3) Both **X** and **Y** are used in the considered mathematical framework.

In order to be clearer I wish to share some of my notions about this question.

Here is a quote taken from Wikipedia:

"A cardinal number λ is a weak limit cardinal if λ is neither a successor cardinal nor zero. This means that one cannot "reach" λ from another cardinal by repeated successor operations. These cardinals are sometimes called simply "limit cardinals" when the context is clear."

By Cantorian mathematical framework, actual infinity is (at least) defined in terms of sets, such that |**N**| is the weak limit cardinal of the set of all natural numbers (where |**N**| is the smallest weak limit cardinal).

If one defines actual infinity by going beyond sets, then any non-finite cardinal number that is based on sets, is inaccessible to actual infinity (it can't measure actual infinity), and therefore it can't have an accurate value (being inaccessible means permanently under construction).

This is exactly what I do by defining a given circle (which its circumference > 0) as a non-composed object (it is not defined as a collection (or more specifically, set) of objects (set of points, in this case)).

So, **x** (the circle's circumference) > 0, where the division operation is used here to define the number of points on the circle (I use the term "on" in order to indicate that a given circle is not defined as a collection (or more specifically, set) of objects (set of points, in this case)).

---

Let us use the framework of modular arithmetic in order to examine the concept of cardinal numbers, which "are a generalization of the natural numbers used to measure the cardinality (size) of sets" (quoted from Wikipedia).

An example:

Let **B** be a point and let **A** be a non-composed circle, such that it is not defined as a set of points.

Let the circumference of the non-composed circle be **x**, such that **x** > 0.

Let the division operation be used here in order to denote the number of **B**s on **A** (we are using here the term "on" in order to indicate that **A** is not defined as a set of **B** objects).

By this framework:

**x**/0 indicates that there are 0 **B**s on **A** (**A** is not defined as a set of **B** objects).

**x**/1 indicates that there is  1 **B** on **A** (**A** is not defined as a set of **B** objects).

**x**/2 indicates that there are 2 **B**s on **A** (**A** is not defined as a set of **B** objects).

**x**/3 indicates that there are 3 **B**s on **A** (**A** is not defined as a set of **B** objects).

Etc. ad infinitum … (where **A** is not defined as a set of **B** objects).

By this framework:

**a.** **x**/0 is a valid mathematical expression, which indicates that **A** is non-composed (**A** is not defined as a set of **B** objects).

**b.** By **a.**, No cardinal number > 0 of **B**s on **A**, defines **A** as non-composed (exactly because **A** is not defined as a set of **B** objects).

**c.** By **b.**, **A** is defined in terms of actual infinity, where any non-finite cardinal number is a measurement of potential infinity (which means that infinite sets are defined in terms of potential infinity).

**d.** By **c.**, no non-finite set has an accurate cardinal number (by this framework non-finite sets are defined in terms of potential infinity), since *it is inaccessible* to **A**, which is defined in terms of actual infinity.

**e.** Such framework is non-Cantorian.

The usefulness of such framework:

It defines infinite sets (or more generally, infinite collections of objects) as open systems, which may lead to better understanding of non-entropic systems (for example, living systems can be researched by mathematical tools that do not define the size of non-finite sets by fixed values, as done in case of finite sets).

Moreover, by looking at **A** as a non-composed 1-dim string-like object, it is actually used to gather any number > 0 of **B**s into collections (of 0-dim beads-like objects), so we get a simple non-Cantorian model of the concept of set, which is a particular case of the concept of collection (generally, any pair of (**n**,**k**) dims, such that **n**=non-negative integer and **k**=non-negative integer > **n**, can be used (which means that modular arithmetic framework is some particular case of the considered mathematical framework)).

Comment: Calculus is an example if you consider its foundations which reside on set theory and recall that the limit operation and analysis encompass potential infinite.

Comment: The title question is interesting, but most of the post does not help and should be deleted (most users would not read a wall of text). What "accessible" or " permanently under construction" mean in the opening lines is unclear and clarifying that might help. But if "actual" and "potential" are assigned some technical meanings then this is a technical question for Math SE or Math Overflow, not us.

Comment: @Conifold, in order to know the meaning of "(in)accessible" or "permanently under construction", one needs to read what you call my "wall of text". If you actually read it, then it may be transformed from wall into a bridge to the considered subject. So please take your time for this transformation in your mind, if you still think that "The title question is interesting". Thank you.

Comment: @Penguin, by axiomatic set theory actual infinity is based on the notion that non-finite number of objects are measured by an accurate value (transfinite cardinal number, for example |N|). My question is about a mathematical framework that goes beyond the notion of set in order to define actual infinity. Actually the aim of my question is to extend the understanding of potential/actual infinity beyond the notion of collection (where set is a particular case of collection).

Comment: If you could prove mathematically that the infinity between 0 and 1 is the same entity as the infinity between 1 and infinity. You would prove that humans have no free will... Since you would be proving that the future already exists. There's a thought.

Comment: @Richard,  Please think about a mathematical framework where past and present are defined in terms of potential infinity and future is defined in terms of actual infinity. By such framework potential infinity is inaccessible to actual infinity and we get an open system, where the future (actual infinity) can't be determined by any amount of steps in the past or in the present (please think about the notion of horizon (as actual infinity), it is inaccessible by any amount of steps that were taken in the past or currently taken in the present (they are understood as potential infinity).

Comment: @Richard, Also please be aware that time may not be considered in many mathematical frameworks, in case that they are based on logical reasoning, where time is not involved.

Comment: @Richard:  I don't know what you mean specifically by "the same entity".  You can put numbers in the (0,1] range in one-to-one correspondence with numbers in the [1... range by using reciprocals.

Comment: Is there any mathematical proof that there is only one kind of infinity?

Comment: Having read the wall of text, I see what "accessible" might mean (it isn't actually defined), but not "permanently under construction".  I don't understand how, if B is a point, and A doesn't contain points, B can be on A, and I particularly don't understand how more than one B can be on A, given that B is a singular object.    I don't get the idea that a noncomposed object has any relation to infinity (in normal geometry, a circle has infintely many points, but you've left that way behind).  As far as I can tell, this is nonsense.

Comment: @David Thomley, A is, at least, 1-dim object , which its existence is not determined by any number of 0-dim objects along it. By defining this existence as Actual Infinity (AI), no infinite set of 0-dim objects along the 1-dim object, is accessible to AI existence. In other words, it is impossible to define a collection of infinite set of 0-dim objects along the 1-dim object by fixed cardinality like |N| (a set of finitely many 0-dims along 1-dim has a fixed cardinality since it is finitely weaker than AI, where any infinite set is infinitely weaker than AI).

Comment: More details are given in www.internationalskeptics.com/forums/showpost.php?p=12412827&postcount=3095
 and forward.

Comment: If the non-composed existence of, at least, ____ is defined as AI, then a non-finite collection (a composed existence) is endlessly weaker than the existence of AI. In that sense potential infinity is not an existence that becomes closer and closer to AI, but exactly the opposite. By finitely weaker I mean that there is an end for a collection's existence to become weaker than  AI. By this reasoning, less you composed, more you exist (where the term existence is not restricted to any particular abstract or non-abstract form).

Comment: @doromshadmi Now you are going out of your way to pretend I am being awful to you instead of trying to make sense. This is not about your ego. I am out of here.  II have deleted my answer and I suggest people who respect decent argument to delete their answers, too.  This notion of 'constructed' is nonsense in Classical mathematics and automatic in Intuitionistic mathematics (time either exists or it doesn't), and you dare not avoid the nonsense concept and say anything, or you will be taken to task.

Comment: @jobermark No ego is involved here, just the simple notion that **there exists** a mathematical object without points along it, exactly as **there exists** {} without any member.

Comment: @doromshadmi  I have not contested that.  I asked whether space is composed of its contents or not.  *You didn't answer*.  Don't *attack* me by *inventing* things I supposedly said but didn't.  Give a correct, complete and meaningful definition of 'composed' or do not insist people use this undefined and internally inconsistent concept just to serve you.

Comment: @doromshadmi  Being pointlessly pushy and insulting is about ego.

Comment: @user9166 said "I asked whether space is composed of its contents or not" My answer: In my framework, given dimension > 0, it is not a collection of smaller dimensions.

Comment: Generally, I suggest that the very essence of being conscious, is the linkage among at least two levels of dimensions, such that the higher dimension is percepted as non-composed wholeness, which enables the transision between parallel (at once) and serial (step by step) perception of the lower dimension(s).

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there is a theory needing both notions, namely modern set theory.

It has finished or actual infinity, guaranteed by the axiom of infinity. There are all infinite sets actually infinite by the axiom of extensionality.

However there is no set of all sets. That means the hierarchy of sets is not complete. But since ordinal numbers and also cardinality have no upper bound, this hierarchy is potentially infinite.

Comment: if the notion of actual infinity is defined not in terms of composed forms like sets (for example, at least, ___ is axiomatically defined as a non-composed form), then the axiom of infinity of modern set theory does not guarantee sets (which composed forms) in terms of actual infinity.